# TNSLSR on port 8080

Tags: tomcat, oracle-apex

I am trying to set up Tomcat 7 and need this to be on port 8080, but I have the following showing when I complete a netstat -plnt | grep ':80'

> tcp 0 0 :::8080 :::* LISTEN 3361/tnslsnr

I believe this might be to do with my Oracle XE / Apex install, but I cannot see where to change it.

Any help my appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify if the database is using the port, login to SQL Plus as the SYS user and issue the command:

```
SELECT DBMS_XDB.GETHTTPPORT FROM DUAL;
```

If the port is 8080, you can change the port to another value by issuing the following command:

```
EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(8088);
```